# BLE iOS Nativescript: Failure to broadcast data

Tags: javascript, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am currently attempting to implement BLE advertising+scanning in nativescript by expanding on [Git code](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth), adding broadcasting functionality to this. In Android I already have successfully constructed an advertisement and I can scan and parse this both under iOS and Android.

However, my iOS attempts are currently failing on putting actual data into the service: If no characteristic is included, I get an error* which apparently translates to an invalid value and as a result, while there is a broadcast it does not include the service. Following a tutorial I found* (after translating its code to javascript-style), I should use `setCharacteristics` on the CBMutableService. However, adding characteristics results in a warning that `setCharacteristics` is not an available function.

```
var kServiceUUID = NSString.stringWithString("2EACE71A-1F75-426E-833F-E77CB58F7201")
var kCharacteristicUUID = NSString.stringWithString("D40670C5-4ECC-4776-8661-B8A11C2833B3");
var serviceUUID = [CBUUID.UUIDWithString(kServiceUUID)];
var characteristicUUID = [CBUUID.UUIDWithString(kCharacteristicUUID)];
var message = arg.message || "No message configured.";
var service = CBMutableService.alloc().initWithTypePrimary(serviceUUID, true);
var service = CBMutableService.alloc().initWithTypePrimary(serviceUUID, true);
var characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic.alloc().initWithTypePropertiesValuePermissions(characteristicUUID, CBCharacteristicPropertyRead | CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify, "test", CBAttributePermissionsReadable);
service.setCharacteristics([characteristic]);
Bluetooth._state.periManager.addService(service);
var dict = NSDictionary.alloc().initWithObjectsForKeys(["test2"],[kServiceUUID]);
Bluetooth._state.periManager.startAdvertising(dict);
```

I will now get

> "CONSOLE LOG file:///app/main-view-model.js:199:32: TypeError: service.setCharacteristics is not a function. (In 'service.setCharacteristics([characteristic])', 'service.setCharacteristics' is undefined)"

As error. However, not adding a characteristic will give me

> CBMutableService: 0x17ef4bd0 Primary = YES, UUID = 2EACE71A-1F75-426E-833F-E77CB58F7201, Included Services = (null), Characteristics = (null)

as service but no services in the scanresult.

*I program under iOS and am currently using Windows, because I can only log into iOS at work. Due to this I do not currently have the links available.

Comment: Update: I discovered that I can directly set the characteristics instead by using service.characteristics = <...>. I did have to adjust the characteristic to not use an array of the UUID but the UUID itself. Still not successfully broadcasting, likely because I'm failing to put a value in there, but the characteristic itself is being added correctly to the service.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics field is accessible directly, however the characteristic itself needs to be correct, with a single serviceUUID:

```
service.characteristics = [characteristic];
```

Updated version of the code (still incomplete):

```
var kServiceUUID = NSString.stringWithString("2EACE71A-1F75-426E-833F-E77CB58F7201");
var kCharacteristicUUID = NSString.stringWithString("D40670C5-4ECC-4776-8661-B8A11C2833B3");
var serviceUUID = CBUUID.UUIDWithString(kServiceUUID);
var characteristicUUID = CBUUID.UUIDWithString(kCharacteristicUUID);
var service = CBMutableService.alloc().initWithTypePrimary(serviceUUID, true);
var characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic.alloc().initWithTypePropertiesValuePermissions(characteristicUUID, CBCharacteristicPropertyRead | CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify, null, CBAttributePermissionsReadable);
service.characteristics = [characteristic];
```

This code is still incomplete, because the characteristic doesn't have a value yet, but the service itself will not complain about the characteristic.